# Why does the LCD show only black in Live View in manual mode on T3i, until I half-press the shutter?

Tags: canon-600d, manual-mode, live-view

I am trying to use my T3i in M mode and also use live mode.  I don't seem to get an image on the LCD screen unless I press the shutter button 1/2.  As soon as I take the picture the LCD screen goes back to all black with a white rectangle outline in the center of the screen.  I will be using the camera in an underwater housing and seeing the live view before I am ready to snap the shutter will be important to me.

Comment: Is your exposure set correctly when this happens? (That is, the pictures you take are well exposed?)

Comment: Have you previewed your photos? If they are black or dark your problem is almost certainly that your exposure is not bright enough.

Comment: Are you planning on using manual mode underwater as well? Ballsy!

Comment: Could you post one of the images with the EXIF info intact?

Answer (score 7):

The Live View screen will by default try to 'mimic' the exposure you're likely to get with the settings you have dialled in.  So in dim light with ISO 100, a fast shutter speed, and a small aperture, you will likely just see a black screen.  When you half press the shutter the camera brightens it up while it meters the scene and so you can see what you're focussing on.

Next time you have this issue just try increasing the shutter speed up through 1 sec, 4 secs, 10 secs etc and you should see the brightness of the image on the lcd display increase.

In a way it's just telling you that your image will be seriously underexposed!!  As you say, when you take the picture, it's just showing you a black screen again (the image preview).

So boost your ISO, use a larger aperture, use a longer shutter speed....whatever it takes to get the correct exposure for the environment you're shooting in :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Canon Rebel T3 and when I turn it on say in auto mode the screen looks fine but when I switch the dial to any of the other modes a little more than half the screen is black and visa versa if I turn it on and the screen is half or more black on auto when I switch the dial to any of the other settings I get a normal full screen.Any idea?Thanks

Sorry my first time on this site and appearantly I put that in the comment section instead of as a question.It has been reposted as a question.

Comment: that doesn't seem terribly relevant to this question, and it certainly isn't an answer.

Comment: Hi Terry.  If you want to ask a question, please use the ask question link above.